# Software to prevent employees from stealing data and using software illegally

Tags: security, monitoring

The environment is a startup with less than 20 people. They use Windows, Mac and Linux systems.

A wireless router is the source of internet for their desktops and laptops. They have their personal phones which can connect to WiFi.
Some systems might have bluetooth too.

- The boss does not want them taking out sensitive company data via
  email or via pen drives or external hard disks or CD's/DVD's.
- Websites they visit, softwares they download and softwares they install are to be monitored and logged.

Need software (one or many) recommendation for the above.
The logs created by the software will be used for audit.
Preferably free and open source software.
Paid ones are also welcome.
Will separate software be required for each OS type?

[These are what I found](http://www.esecurityplanet.com/network-security/10-open-source-security-breach-prevention-and-detection-tools.html). And [this](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2230653/opensource-subnet/data-leak-prevention-finally-gets-an-open-source-alternative.html).

Comment: Yes, you'll need separate software on each OS platform.

Comment: Did you investigate the software under your links? Tell us why they don't meet your requirements.

Comment: Most employees probably use HTTPS, which means that data can not be seen. Do you want to see HTTPS content (which implies installing a reporting agent on everyone's computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as install and using software illegally goes here is an idea.

All non IT department users should be **Standard User** or **Limited User** permissions.  Linux and Mac can have similar accounts.  Almost all linux software is free so piracy of the software is nearly non-existent.  You can't steal software that is freely available for anyone who install the distro of linux to have.

This type of account prevents the installation of anything that requires administrator access.  Their are very few apps that can install under these conditions.  Many parts of the file system and registry are off limits to "Standard Users".  It will be hard to pirate software if that is a concern.

Your IT person reviews, and install ALL software.

As far as preventing them stealing data that is going to be harder.  They can always screen capture, and send via email if they are desperate enough.  You could use bitlocker to encrypt all USB/hdd brought into the company, but that only helps if someone steal a USB/hdd.